# can't play sound on Xcode 4.3

Tags: xcode4.3

I am using Xcode 4.3 and i have a problem with playing sound...
I downloaded this project from an answer i found here from but when i change his file with mine http://dl.dropbox.com/u/63377498/AudioText.zip i can't hear anything. Can be a problem of my simulator? Settings of my mac? I don't know...
That's the code i use:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *theAudio;
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize theAudio = _theAudio;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
NSString *soundPath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sad" ofType:@"caf"];
NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];

NSError *error;
self.theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:&error];
}

- (IBAction)pushBell {
[self.theAudio play];
}
```

Comment: i found out that my sound file has a problem but i do not know why i do have this problem. I tried to change the sound file with another sound and it worked.

Comment: Unless the sound file was composed by [Django Reinhardt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_Reinhardt) this doesn't have to do with django models. Removing the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the answer on my own. I was doing everything right but i used a sound file downloaded from youtube in mp3 format and i converted to .caf format by changing the extension....Thats the reason why i can't play that sound!